# Visual Studio Code - flatten packages in explorer view

Tags: package, visual-studio-code, flatten

I would like to know if anyone knows how to flatten the package structures in Visual Studio Code.

I used to have this in my IntelliJ IDE, but with VS Code I can't find a similar option. I am looking for any solution which could resolve this. Either changing settings or extensions if available.

Answer (score 6):

This is supported [since the 1.41 release (November 2019)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_41#_compact-folders-in-explorer) and enabled by default. VSCode calls this feature "compact folders", and it can be disabled like this:

```
"explorer.compactFolders": false
```

[image]

(gif from the release notes)

Answer (score 0):

For java the only way i found is using this extension 
(it won't change the default file explorer, but you can fold that one and use this one instead).

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-dependency

or goto your VSCode->Extensions and search for  "Java Dependency Viewer".

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code v1.73.1 (latest as of this writing) folders are rendered in a compact form by default. To change this, go to File/Preferences/Settings/Features/Explorer and deselect Compact Folders.

[image]